# broadcasting data to n threads with varying lifetime

Tags: c, multithreading, broadcast, race-condition, glib

I have to send a minor amount of data (~1k bytes) from `thread A` to all threads `threads B-1` to `threads B-n`.

My current implementation is rather complex:

Use `GHashTable` to map queues to `thread id`s. Put all `threads B-x` into a waiting state via `GCond` and `g_cond_wait(_until)`. Push a pointer to the data all threads should receive into each queue from `thread A`, broadcast the update via `g_cond_broadcast` (they all use the same `GCond` instance).
If a thread decides to finish (i.e. remote DC), first remove the Queue from the `GHashTable`, clear the queue and destroy contents. There are some more details I left out (like race conditions, intermediate ref/unref around the wait block).

**Is this a sane approach? How can I improve this. It does not "feel" efficient at all.**

Just for reference, attached some draft code:

```
typedef struct {
    //TODO verify this is not too stupid
    // if we use that mutex too often, all parallel foo is pointless
    GMutex mutex;
    GHashTable *hashmap; //full of queues
    gint refs;
    GDestroyNotify fx_ref;
    GDestroyNotify fx_unref;
} Foo;


Foo *
foo_new (GDestroyNotify fx_ref, GDestroyNotify fx_unref)
{
    Foo *foo;

    foo = g_new0 (Foo, 1);
    g_assert (foo);
    g_mutex_init (&(foo->mutex));
    foo->hashmap = g_hash_table_new_full ();
    foo->refs = 1;
    foo->fx_ref = fx_ref; //just asume this increases the refcount atomically
    foo->fx_unref = fx_unref; //"" decreases ""
    return foo;
}

void
foo_register_thread (Foo *obj, gint threadid)
{
    AQueue *aq;

    foo_lock (obj);
    aq = a_queue_new ((GDestroyNotify)i_do_unref);

    g_hash_table_insert (obj->hashmap, id, aq);
    foo_unlock (obj);
}

void
foo_unregister_thread (Foo *obj, gint threadid)
{
    AQueue *aq;

    foo_lock (obj);
    g_hash_table_remove (obj->hashmap, id);
    // broadcast _after_ removing the queue from the hashtable,
    // so the thread wakes up and quits its foo_thread_wait_until_ready call
    g_cond_broadcast (obj->cond);
    foo_unlock (obj);
    // allow somebody to sneak in
    foo_lock (obj);
    a_queue_unref (aq)
    foo_unlock (obj);
}

void
foo_enqueue (Foo *obj, gpointer data)
{
    GHashTableIter iter;
    gint key;
    GAsyncQueue *queue;

    //wave after wave, not wave intermixing 
    g_mutex_lock (&obj->mutex);

    g_hash_table_iter_init (iter, obj->ht);
    while (g_hash_table_iter_next (&iter, &id, &queue)) {
        if (foo->fx_ref)
            foo->fx_ref (data);
        g_queue_push_tail (queue, data);
    }
    g_cond_broadcast (cond);

    g_mutex_unlock (&obj->mutex);
}


gpointer
foo_thread_pop (Foo *obj, gint id)
{
    AQueue *aq;
    gpointer data = NULL;

    g_return_val_if_fail (obj, NULL);
    g_return_val_if_fail (id>0, NULL);

    foo_lock (obj);
    aq = g_hash_table_lookup (obj->hashmap, id);
    if (aq) {
        data = g_queue_pop_head ((GQueue*)aq);
    }
    foo_unlock (obj);
    return data;
}


/**
 * wait until the queue gets removed or until data is ready to be read
 */
gpointer
foo_thread_wait_until_ready (Foo *obj, gint id)
{
    gpointer data = NULL;
    AQueue *aq;

    foo_lock (obj);
    aq = (AQueue*)g_hash_table_lookup (obj->hashmap, id);
    if (!aq)
        return NULL;

    // just in case stuff gets cleaned up in the meantime
    a_queue_ref (aq);


    while (g_queue_peek_head ((GQueue*)aq)==NULL) {
        g_cond_wait_until (&(obj->cond), &(obj->mutex))
        // make sure queue still exists, if not this means this thread is dying
        if (g_hash_table_lookup (obj->hashmap, id) != (gpointer)aq)
            break;
    }

    data = g_queue_pop_head ((GQueue*)aq);

    a_queue_unref (aq);

    foo_unlock (obj);

    return data;
}


void
foo_destroy (Foo *obj)
{
    g_return_if_fail (obj);
    g_mutex_clear (&obj->mutex);
    g_cond_clear (&obj->cond);
}

void
foo_unref (Foo *obj)
{
    g_return_if_fail (obj);
    if (g_atomic_int_dec_and_test (&obj->refs))
        foo_destroy (obj);
}

void
foo_ref (Foo *obj)
{
    g_return_if_fail (obj);
    g_atomic_int_inc (&obj->refs);
}

void
foo_lock (Foo *obj)
{
    g_return_if_fail (obj);
    g_atomic_int_inc (&obj->refs);
    g_mutex_lock (&obj->mutex);
}

void
foo_unlock (Foo *obj)
{
    g_return_if_fail (obj);
    g_mutex_unlock (&obj->mutex);
    foo_unref (obj);
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell if your approach is sane. What do those threads do? Send the data via TCP? In that case, you should mention that in your question. It could mean that your approach is overcomplicated, using e.g. select() or maybe even a framework like zeromq would be beneficial.

Comment: A 1:N ratio, 1 unspecified (proprietary protocol) and N TCP/IP connections, though introducing more dependencies is not desireable.

Comment: Still then, select() is the way to go. In general, you don't need more than one thread per network card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using fork. Here is a high-level rundown of the algorithm:

Hypothesis: each thread do not need to broadcast back memory to the parent. Each requests can be treated in any order.

- before multithreading (forking), create an array of pointers to struct (the struct provides all the necessary info for treating a queued request). Allocate a shared, mutex-controlled integer with 0 as an initial value.
- fork for as many times as you want. (I used the number of logical CPUs +1 since the parent is mostly idle).

Then every forks goes as follow:

- if the shared integer is not locked, lock it and increment it. unlock it. treat the element in the array corresponding to the prior to increment value.
- if locked, try again later.
- if the value is larger than the global number of requests, exit.

The parent simply waits that all threads are done.

Comment: Think of connections: If I knew how many threads were active at that point of time, then I could just use one async queue and push the object `N`-times and let each thread consume one piece of the queue. But this could leak memory if i.e. one connection closes between push in `thread A` and pop in `thread B-#`. Also the parent probably will never return as I'd expect frequent connections which would cause a linear memory growth over time (as cleanup is required in the parent, correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: the approach I suggest is analoguous to a situation where you could predict how to split the tasks among the threads, predicting how many threads you would run and preparing each thread to execute the subsets that you would have attributed them. Throught sharing a single integer among all the threads (on the parent), you can find that information at run time. This works if all threads are independents (order of tasks execution is not important.